# Сохранение бинарных данных на стороне клиента

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, файлы

Посредством Ajax получаю с сервера файл в бинарном виде. Как я могу его послать на скачивание клиенту?

```
$('#getEpdReport').click(function() {
    var period = $('#period3').val();
    var flsId = $('#flsId3').val();
    var epdId = $('#epdId3').val();
    var data = '{"period":"' + period + '","flsId":"' + flsId + '","epdId":"' + epdId + '"}';
    sendajax('flsEpd/getEpdReport', data, function(response) {
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.download = 'Квитанция ' + period + '.pdf';
        downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Скачать файл';
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(data);
        downloadLink.click();
    });
});
```

На стороне сервера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "lc/housing/jkhkr/flsEpd/getEpdReport", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/pdf;charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody void getEpdReport(@RequestBody String body, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, final ModelMap model) {
    Map<String, String> params = Maps.newHashMap();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String result = "";
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        params = mapper.readValue(body, Map.class);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jkhKrProvider.getEpdReport(params.get("period"), Long.valueOf(params.get("flsId")), Long.valueOf(params.get("epdId"))).getEpdReport());
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) { }    
}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит дать пользователю возможность скачать файл? В случае со статичными файлами это достаточно просто. Что-то вроде этого: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbpLbq3o/). В случае нестатичных файлов по переходу по ссылке файл можно отдавать с помощью Java.

Comment: Ещё интересный вариант с использованием атрибута [download](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-the-html5-download-attribute--cms-23880): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbpLbq3o/1/).

Comment: @Regent, вариант с html5 не подходит, файл не статичный , он получается через ряд веб-сервисов. В моем случае файл приходит на клиент и харнится, соответственно, в response. Дело в том, как из этого response теперь его выдавить клиенту как файл

Comment: @dzrock можно вот так сделать: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbpLbq3o/3/). Если убрать атрибут `download`, то просто файл будет сохраняться с "некрасивым" именем.

Comment: @Regent, слияние? посмотрите дискуссию по ссылке. и, мне кажется, лучше переместиться с вопросами и обсуждениями в чат, а под этим вопросом весь оффтопик поудалять.

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Оттуда, собственно:

```
function setFile( data, fileName, fileType ) {
  // Set objects for file generation.
  var blob, url, a, extension;

    // Get time stamp for fileName.
    var stamp = new Date().getTime();

    // Set MIME type and encoding.
    fileType = ( fileType || "text/csv;charset=UTF-8" );
    extension = fileType.split( "/" )[1].split( ";" )[0];
    // Set file name.
    fileName = ( fileName || "ActiveVoice_" + stamp + "." + extension );

    // Set data on blob.
    blob = new Blob( [ data ], { type: fileType } );

    // Set view.
    if ( blob ) {
        // Read blob.
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );

        // Create link.
        a = document.createElement( "a" );
        // Set link on DOM.
        document.body.appendChild( a );
        // Set link's visibility.
        a.style = "display: none";
        // Set href on link.
        a.href = url;
        // Set file name on link.
        a.download = fileName;

        // Trigger click of link.
        a.click();

        // Clear.
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL( url );
    } else {
        // Handle error.
    }
}
```

Пример, тоже оттуда:
http://jsfiddle.net/a856P/51/